# unable to run python packages stored in EFS when connected to aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I have installed certain packages to efs by mounting it on an ec2 instance(ubuntu). After successfully connecting the same efs to aws lambda, while running the lamda function i get an error 'ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051''. Not sure what is it about. I verified that all my packages are in efs but unable to successfully run lambda.

log - 2021-03-10T21:06:04.834+05:30 Downloading urllib3-1.26.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (137 kB)

2021-03-10T21:06:04.919+05:30   Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17

2021-03-10T21:06:04.942+05:30   Downloading certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)

2021-03-10T21:06:04.947+05:30   Using legacy 'setup.py install' for en-core-web-sm, since package 'wheel' is not installed.

2021-03-10T21:06:05.066+05:30   Installing collected packages: tqdm, numpy, blis, chardet, idna, urllib3, certifi, requests, cymem, murmurhash, preshed, catalogue, wasabi, plac, srsly, thinc, spacy, en-core-web-sm

2021-03-10T21:06:05.068+05:30

Copy
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried uploading packages in layer?

Comment: the amount of packages i need to install is over 1gb as it is a machine learning model. hence i couldn’t use layers